# Append URI segment

Tags: php, codeigniter

I love the way SO handles URIs. I'd like to mimic the same behaviour in CI. I have a controller called `Users` and the index method should take one argument, that being the user ID. I search the DB for the username associated with that user ID. Consider that `user:1` has `username:Santa Claus`, how can I append the username to the URI, so that it looks like `http://foo.com/users/1/santa-claus`

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Users extends CI_Controller {

function index($uID = 0) {
    if ($uID > 0) {
        $this->load->model('users_model');
        $uname = $this->users_model->_getUsername($uID);

        #append somehow..       

    } else {
        echo('load all users');
    }
}

}
```

---

Just to be clear, I'm trying to achieve this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11041075/704015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

application/config/routes.php

```
$route['users/(:num)/(:any)'] = 'users/index/$1';
```

Controller

```
    function index($uID = 0) {
         .....
         $uname = strtolower(str_replace(" ", "-", $uname));

         header("Location: ".base_url()."user/".$uID."/".$uname);
```

Please include a condition do something else incase username is already present to avoid loop.

Comment: You correctly predicted that it would cause a redirect loop. My first thought is to explode the URI and check the last segment against the value of `$uname`, but I don't know how reliable that would be.

Comment: I added this condition: `$uri = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
   if ($uname != end($uri)) {...}`

Answer (score 0):

This in your config/routes.php

```
 $route['users/(:num)/(:any)'] = 'users/$1/$2';
```

and this in your controller

```
public function users($id,$username = FALSE)
{
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I don't know why this would work either. If I accessed the method and didn't include a second argument, how would it search the DB for the username associated with the user ID, and append the username to the URI?

Comment: Pretty simple really you can append the information you retrieve via javascript (so you dont have to do a redirect)

Like so:
window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/new-url");

more details here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338642/updating-address-bar-with-new-url-without-hash-or-reloading-the-page?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: Ideally, I would create all important functionality without relying on JS.